# Resize Android ImageView on Keyboard open, keep aspect ratio

Tags: android, layout, keyboard, imageview

I am having some issues with setting some image as the background in an Android application. The problem is that I want the image to fill in the space in the middle of the layout, but when the keyboards opens, it gets stretched and doesn't keep the aspect ratio.

Here are 2 diagrams explaining the layout :

[image: Keyboard closed]
[image: Keyboard open]

Here is my current code related to this problem :
`layout.xml`

```xml
   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/background_image">
            </ImageView>

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/itemsSetup"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1">

            </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>


        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:background="@color/colorDarkLighter"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            ... 
       </LinearLayout>
```

`AndroidManifest.xml`

```xml
  <activity
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
  ...
  </activity>
```

I can't use
`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` or `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"` because I want the bottom to be higher than the keyboard as it opens and also keep the header, as shown on the diagrams above.

I have tried setting the background image programatically as explained in other threads with

```
getActivity().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.background_image);
```

The problem is that when doing so, the image gets stretched and doesn't keep the aspect ratio.

Has anyone been able to combine both, resizing the layout with everything still on the screen and keeping the aspect ratio of an image ?

Thanks.

Comment: How about on your imageview `android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:scaleType="fitXY"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"}`

Comment: thanks but then the image does not fill up the space on the X axis